# Dealing with duplicates in SSRS parameters

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

So I've been working on a report for a while now. I'm still a noob, so I'm not sure how to deal with my current problem, which are duplicate parameter values.

Here's a screenshot of my parameters. [Paramater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lrhG.png) One parameter dropdown has to do with my Programs, while the second is Activities. As you can see, there are duplicates of "Basics for", when both programs are selected.

Here's a snippet of my database. [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgT7E.png) A different ID is attached to the two different programs.

Finally, here's the code for my parameters.

**Program:**

```
SELECT distinct
A.ProgramID, A.ProgramName

FROM dwh.Bks_DWH_Programs A
INNER JOIN dwh.Bks_DWH_OrgUnits d on A.ProgramOrgUnitID = d.OrgUnitID

WHERE d.OrgUnitParentID in (@OP) and 
d.OrgUnitID in (@OU)
```

**Activity:**

```
SELECT distinct A.Activity_ID, A.Activity_Name

FROM dwh.Bks_DWH_Activities A
INNER JOIN dwh.Bks_DWH_Programs aa on a.Activity_EntityID = aa.ProgramID
INNER JOIN dwh.Bks_DWH_OrgUnits d on aa.ProgramOrgUnitID = d.OrgUnitID

WHERE d.OrgUnitParentID in (@OP) and 
d.OrgUnitID in (@OU) and
aa.ProgramID in (@TP)

ORDER by A.Activity_ID
```

I understand WHY there are duplicates (since the programs have different IDs), but I'm just wondering if there's a way to somehow join the two? It's annoying having duplicates in the dropdown.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you not do something like `SELECT distinct A.Activity_ID, A.Activity_Name + aa.ProgramName AS Activity_Name` to make then unique?

Comment: This works too! I like that it shows the program next to the activity. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for comment. I suppose you could look at the name of the parameter. So essentially you would just remove `A.Activity_ID` from your Activity query. But then you would also need to do something different in your main query (assuming you're filtering on the `A.Activity_ID` values being passed).

Your Activity query would look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Activity_Name
FROM...
```

And your main query would have something like:

```
WHERE d.OrgUnitParentID IN (@OP) 
AND d.OrgUnitID IN (@OU) 
AND aa.ProgramID IN (@TP)
AND a.Activity_Name = @[YourActivityParameter]
```

or...

```
AND a.Activity_Name IN (@[YourActivityParameter])
```

Note: This may have performance implications.

Comment: I didn't think it would be something so simple! There doesn't seem to be any change in performance either. Thank you!

Sorry, I can't upvote you yet.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help... Performance issues might come as your database gets larger. But there's also a chance that it won't be affected. Good luck!